# how to create a dictionary out of a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

let us say i have a dictionary 
`{'a':'b',c':'d',e':'f'},{'a':'h',c':'i',e':'j'},{'a':'k',c':'l',e':'m'}` in data.json i want to create a dictionary like :

`{'d':'f','i':'j','l':'m'}`

i tried doing with python

```py
with open('data.json','r') as f:
        json_data = [json.loads(line) for  line in f]
        for item in json_data:
            print(item)
```

output and input

```
json_data={'a':'b',c':'d',e':'f'},{'a':'h',c':'i',e':'j'},{'a':'k',c':'l',e':'m'}
output={'d':'f','i':'j','l':'m'}"
```

Comment: I guess you have to do it manually by hard-coding the new **dict** with index/key value in every **dict** of your `json` and then print the output

Comment: What is the logic for the expected output?

Comment: whats the pattern to get it?

Comment: input is a dictionary {'app' : 'bay', 'caa' : 'daa' , 'ebay ' : 'foo' },{'app' : 'hop' ,'caa' : 'Ink','ebay' : ' jet'} , { 'app' : 'kaa' , 'caa' : 'lnk' , 'ebay' : 'man'}                                                 output : {'daa' : 'foo','Ink':'jet','lnk':'man'}